# Pagination, size of page, table of pages - conclusion about size of operational memory

Tags: memory-management, paging, cpu-architecture, page-tables

> Lets consider that size of page is equal to `1 KB`. One entry in table
>   takes `2B`.  Table of pages takes not more than one page (so `<= 1KB`).
>
> Can we conclude that size of operational memory is `<= 512 KB` ?

A correct answer is No, however I can't understand it. For me, answer is yes - look at my reasoning at show me where I am wrong, please.

Table contains `<=1024B/2B=512=2^9` entries in table of pages.  Size of page is `1024B=2^10B`, so offset takes not more than `<=10` bits.  Number of page takes `<=9` bits - because we have `512=2^9` entries.  Hence, `9+10=19`. Therefore `<=2^19 bits` make it possible to address `<= 2^19 B=2^9KB=512KB`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Does "operational memory" mean the amount of virtual memory a single process can map at once?  Or does it mean the amount of physical memory a machine can use?

Comment: It is about physical memory - I think so.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I believe in these CPU architecture contexts it refers to primary memory (physical).

Comment: When it comes to physical memory the possibility would be that since a page table entry is 2 bytes (16bits) wide (and assuming all the bits can be used for physical page indexing) that you have the possibility that there are 65536 physical page frames (0-65535) of 1024 bytes each which could suggest a system with as much as 64MB of operational memory. So to me the answer is no since I think there could be as much as 64MB of operational memory.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, I have an answer almost ready to post explaining that.  But then I realized I wasn't sure if that was a valid assumption about table entries.  I guess if virtual address space is only 2^9 pages, that works, so every page maps to a specific PTE.  I was going to say something about how a kernel could give the illusion of having more pages mapped by handling page faults and mapping in a page that the process has mapped, but that didn't fit in the PT.  (i.e. treat the PT like a software-managed TLB). But that doesn't work if there can only be 2^9 pages of virtual address space

Comment: But I am making assumptions without context of how your course is teaching this. For instance on x86 hardware not all of the bits in a page table entry can be used for indexing physical page frames. It would actually depend on how the hypothetical hardware your course is discussing does paging.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, you are right. This assumption must be implicite, because of unclear contents of task.

Comment: @MichaelPetch and OP: If this is all the information you're given, it's fairly straightforward to say that it doesn't let you rule out a design that can use more than 512k of physical memory.  You don't need to make any assumptions.  New information (assumptions you were supposed to make, but left out of the question) could change the answer to "yes", or require coming up with a different counter-example, but the question is totally valid with only this much information.

Comment: PeterCordes: Actually I didn't say that this question has no answer. I made an assumption that shows that there **could be** far more than 512KB of operational memory. And since that is possible then the answer is no. And I actually guess that is why the course work also suggests the answer is no.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: sorry, I was mainly addressing the OP's last comment that implicit assumptions were required.  I meant to just ping you as well with the comment in case you were interested, but I got the wording wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page table entry is 2B, so a table entry can point to one of 2^16 physical pages.  That's 2*16 kiB (because pages are 1kB).  So a kernel can make use of up to 65536 kiB (64MiB) of physical memory.

This assumes that the entire page table entry (PTE) is a physical page number.  That can work if the position of a PTE within the page table associates it with a virtual address.  i.e. 9 bits of a virtual address are used as an index into the PT, to select a PTE.

**We can't assume that the machine *does* work this way, but similarly we can't assume that it *doesn't***, until we have more information.

Given just the info in the question, we can conclude:

- Usable physical memory can be anything up to 65536kiB.
- Up to 512 virtual pages can be mapped at once (512kiB).
- Not much else!  Many possibilities are open.

---

A more likely design would have a valid/invalid bit in each PTE.

If a PTE's contents (rather than its location) indicate which virtual page it maps, it would be possible to map a large virtual address space onto very few physical pages.  This address space would necessarily be sparsely mapped, but the kernel could give a process the *illusion* of having a lot of active mappings by keeping a separate table of what the mappings *should* be.

So on a page fault, the kernel checks to see if the page should have been mapped.  If so, it puts the mapping in the PTE and resumes the process.  (This kind of thing happens in real OSes, and it's called a [minor page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Minor).)

In this design, the kernel's use of the page table to hold a subset of the real mappings would be analogous to a [software-managed TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#TLB_miss_handling).  (Of course, this architecture could have a non-coherent TLB that requires invalidation after every PTE modification, so this would probably perform horribly).